# Можно ли говорить «обрели» вместо «сделали»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов

Хотел услышать ответ от специалистов, учителей русского языка. Можно ли говорить «обрели ваши руки», будет ли это означать «сделали ваши руки»?

Comment: *Контексту* мне, *контексту*! Тагир, опишите ситуацию — тогда и подумаем.

Answer (score 1):

"Ваши руки обрели свободу" - в значении, если были до этого связаны (как пример).
"Это ваших рук дело" - про ситуацию, обычно с негативным оттенком.
"Сделали ваши руки" - про физические предметы, как правило. (Ваза сделана вашими руками)